# How to copy/paste text between MIT Scheme and Windows

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

I want to copy/paste some text between MIT Scheme's Edwin and Windows. Is there a way?

Right now I open source code in notepad, copy/paste there, save and close, return to Edwin and synchronize. It's not convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user/Edwin.html), it's stated that

> Edwin is very similar to GNU Emacs—you should refer to the GNU Emacs manual for information about Edwin's commands and key bindings

So my guess is that you have to:

- First set a mark at the beginning and at the end of the text to be copied: `[Ctrl-spacebar]`
- Then copy it: `[Meta-W]`
- And to paste back from windows: `[Ctrl-Y]`

Comment: thank you very much, it works (except no second `^-space` should be pressed). Seems so obvious in retrospect.

Answer (score 1):

The code of Edwin was creating from a branch of Emacs. In emacs the copy-paste is called `yank`.

The yank ring interacts with the graphical interface .

Look [here](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/CopyAndPaste) at a detailed description of the interface.

Comment: I siggest you to run mit scheme via the *repl* of emacs, not via mit-scheme -- edit